Singularity (aks Apptainer) not able mount fusemount inside container on RHEL 8.10 system be hardened with CIS benchmark
I built a new RHEL 8.10 x86_64 with CIS hardened, and run Singularity/Apptainer on the system, but it hangs at stage mountGeneric()                Mounting /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/fuse/0 to /var/lib/apptainer/mnt/session/final/tmp
I disable Audit service and removed all Audit rules out of the system, its works.
The question, why Audit rules could block Singularity/Apptainer engine? How can we exclude Singularity/Apptainer out of Audit monitor?
